# How do I install Terraformer on my Windows machine?

Tags: installation, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+, terraform-template-file

I have gone through some online blogs, can someone explain how in the world should I install terraformer on my machine? There is no exe file or anything. I have followed blogs online, have no idea where I am going wrong, it just doesn't show up in the cmd.
Would be a great help!! Thanks!
Blogs I don't understand:

https://neillwturner.medium.com/using-terraformer-to-generate-terraform-files-from-your-existing-cloud-environment-f2923a77d586

https://faun.pub/terraformer-5036241f90cc

I have no idea how to go about this

Comment: I followed the instructions in the README.MD at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer/blob/master/README.md and was able to build it on Windows.  

Have you tried that?  If so, what errors did you receive?

Comment: Actually, I had trouble following these instructions I think. I get terraformer is not recognized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Chocolatey package manager to install on windows `choco install terraformer`.

According to the readme file you can also do the following:

> Windows
>
> 1. Install Terraform - https://www.terraform.io/downloads
> 2. Download exe file for required provider from here - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer/releases
> 3. Add the exe file path to path variable
> 4. Create a folder and initialize the terraform provider and run terraformer commands from there  For AWS - refer https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/aws-build?in=terraform/aws-get-started

Answer (score -2):

$ brew install terraformer

---

$ terraformer -v

this is for mac only

Comment: The question seems to be how to install on windows.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32271878)